# How do I add another keyboards into Remix OS (Vietnam, Cambodia, Thailand Keyboards)

Tags: android-emulator, android-softkeyboard, vmware-player, southeast-asian-languages

I have a problem which are I cannot add another keyboards namely, Vietnam, Cambodia and Thailand. I cannot change the Keyboard from English language to Vietnam, Cambodia and Thailand languages. I have tried Khmer Smart Keyboard, Cambodia Keyboard APK and Phum Keyboard for Cambodia keyboard; Keyboard ManMan, Gadgetdoor Thai Keyboard, Thai Gingerbread KB and Thai Pack Without ALM97774503 for Thailand keyboard.

My host OS is Windows 7. I use VM-ware player to run Remix OS and Remix OS is marshmallow. How do I add another keyboards into Remix OS please?

Kindly please help me out. Any suggestion, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think at now you can use Google keyboard that has those languages already: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en

It's also easy to switch between language.